# CSP Finding Path

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, graph-theory, dijkstra

I am able to implement the default uniform cost search (python) to find the shortest path between two nodes (path cost). I followed this pseudocode:

Answer (score 1):

This is called the 'Constrained Shortest Path Problem' and has a pseudo-polynomial time solution using Dijkstra's algorithm. Instead of just having nodes, our new graph has `(node, spent_fuel)` pairs, which increases the number of edges and vertices by a factor of the maximum fuel budget `B`.

If your original algorithm for Dijkstra's ran in time `O(|E| + |V| log |V|)`, where `E` is your edge set (or actions, in this case) and `V` is your vertex set, the new algorithm will run in time `O(B|E| + B|V| log (B|V|))`. If your budget isn't much larger than the size of your graph, this is not so bad; otherwise you'll need more advanced methods of solving, since Constrained Shortest Paths is NP-Hard when the budget is unbounded.

Here, we still process the `(node, fuel_cost)` pairs in monotonically-increasing order by distance, so the first time we explore the target, we have the minimum distance to reach it under budget.

Here's the pseudocode. There are some optimizations possible: you can filter out `(node, fuel_cost, path_cost)` if we know of a path to this node with `fuel <= fuel_cost` and a distance less than or equal to `path_cost`. You can do this, for example, by building a binary-search-tree for each node, and only consider `(node, fuel_cost)` if its path-cost is smaller than that of any `(node, fuel_cost + c), c >= 0`.

```
function Constrained-Uniform-Cost-Search(problem)

start <- node with State = problem.initial-state, Path-Cost 0


// Elements of frontier are (node, fuel_cost) pairs, ordered by distance. 
frontier <- priority queue, contains (start, 0)

explored <- empty set

while frontier is not empty:
    (node, fuel_cost) <- pop(frontier)
    
    if node == target: return Solution(node, fuel_cost)
    add (node, fuel_cost) to explored

    for action in problem.Actions(node):
        (neighbor, neighbor_fuel) <- Child-Node(node, fuel_cost, action)

        if neighbor_fuel > problem.Budget: continue

        if (neighbor, neighbor_fuel) not in explored or frontier:
            frontier <- insert((neighbor, neighbor_fuel), frontier)
        
        else if (neighbor, neighbor_fuel) in frontier with higher Path-Cost:
            replace that frontier node with (neighbor, neighbor_fuel)

return Failure
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you so much. Could you explain the time complexity of this modified algorithm? O(E + V*B log (V*B)), where B is your maximum budget

Comment: Why is V multiplied by the Budget? And why do we log2 it?

Comment: @fapiyas739 After checking the code to calculate the runtime, I noticed an error: that runtime is only guaranteed when the edge-distances are all equal. I've rewritten the algorithm to fix this and match the problem notation you showed. The issue is that Dijkstra's algorithm requires you to decrease the keys inside the priority queue to limit the queue's size.

Comment: @fapiyas739 . The time complexity comes from the normal [running time of Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm#Running_time) with an optimal priority-queue. The graph has `B` times more edges and vertices, so the first term should be `B|E|` instead. Also, this is based on finite graphs with vertices and edges, so it might not fit your 'problem-state and actions' formulation here if the graph is infinite.